# Search locations inside a particular city in Google Places Apis

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using Google Places Apis to filter results inside a particular city.I am able to filter results.but it also shows results out side of that city.
For example if I set LatLngBounds of DELHI city and searching for a location  in city NEWYORK. It also gives me result of NEWYORK city(but NEWYORK's LatLng is not lies inside DELHI).

How can I restrict my results to a particular city?

This is my PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter class

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBufferUtils;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PlaceAutocompleteAdapter
        extends ArrayAdapter<AutocompletePrediction> implements Filterable {


    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> mResultList;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;

    public PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient,
            LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        super(context,R.layout.simple_expandble_text_view_item, R.id.text1);
        mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    public void setBounds(LatLngBounds bounds) {
        mBounds = bounds;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AutocompletePrediction getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        AutocompletePrediction item = getItem(position);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        textView1.setText(item.getDescription());
        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    mResultList = getAutocomplete(constraint);
                    if (mResultList != null) {
                        results.values = mResultList;
                        results.count = mResultList.size();
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                if (resultValue instanceof AutocompletePrediction) {
                    return ((AutocompletePrediction) resultValue).getDescription();
                } else {
                    return super.convertResultToString(resultValue);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                    Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                    mBounds, mPlaceFilter);
            AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                    .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error contacting API: " + status.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                autocompletePredictions.release();
                return null;
            }
            return DataBufferUtils.freezeAndClose(autocompletePredictions);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I have include my code

Comment: can you  please output the mBounds you are using? I mean a real log call to mBounds values in the getAutocomplete function you did.

Comment: Yes , and I get current mBounds here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation:

> > **public abstract PendingResult getAutocompletePredictions (GoogleApiClient client, String query, LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter)**
> >     Returns autocomplete predictions for a query based on the names and addresses of places. For more information, see the developer's guide.
>
> This method performs a network lookup.
>
> Access to this method is subject to quota restrictions. See Usage Limits for more details.
>
> Parameters
>
> *query*    The query string for which the autocomplete predictions are to be fetched.
>
> *bounds*    **A geographic bounds. If present, returned predictions will be biased towards places in this area.**
>
> *filter*   A filter to use for restricting the returned predictions. If null, a filter with no constraints will be used.

The description for "bounds" is to return **biased** predictions. So those are not filtered, but biased basing on this bounds. This means that the results inside the bound should have higher priority, but those will not be the only results.

**UPDATE**

As of April 2018 Google added possibility to specify how to treat the bounds in autocomplete predictions. Now you can use the  `getAutocompletePredictions()` method of `GeoDataClient` class with `boundsMode` parameter.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50134855/5140781 for more details.

Comment: But what to do to get Exact Results.Should I have to Filter results manually.

Comment: if you want to get the filtered result (bounding box only) you have to manually filter using the location of the place and the bounding box. Looking at the APIs, you don't get the LatLng position of each place, but only the ID, so it would require an api request to obtain the Place object from the ID for each result (1000 results = 1000 api call!), and that would not be a nice solution.
If anyway you want to do it, just check that the LatLng position of the place is inside the bounding box; check lat and Lng min/max of the bounding box wrt the place location

Answer (score 2):

The code you have written is right. I also had done this but never tried with bounds. I checked with bounds and gone through the documentation, its written that it will give biased results that means it will give results with priority to the within the given bounds.

Here is the documentation link

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

Comment: Hi Nigam Patro , Thanks for answering.I read the google documents before posting the question but I am asking for a way to restrict the result inside my bounds.Is there any way to achieve this?Thanks for your time.