# Android Map to search only within a city

Tags: android, google-maps, search, autocomplete

I'm currently making an android app that has a map in it. I have successfully added the map and can search places. From what I have searched online, I can set my city and limit my search only to my country.

Does anyone know how to limit my search only within a city?

Answer (score 1):

it's quite tricky solution, but you can do it by following steps:

**Step1**: Google places allows you only biasing search results from specified LatLngBounds (in your case city bounds), but search engine may still return *Place* outside given bounds. See [Restrict autocomplete results](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#restrict_autocomplete_results) for more details. I think this is sufficient, but if you need strict restriction, follow step2.

**Step2**: With all search results from *Step1* call [Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi#getPlaceById(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String...)) to get detail info about each *Place*. You'll get among other things LatLng of each place. Then you can check if each *Place* lies within given bounds: `bounds.contains(LatLng)` and if not, remove it manually from search results.

**HOWEVER**: *Step2* solution multiplies number of requests on PlacesAPI and you should think twice if you really need this strict restriction!

**UPDATE**

As of April 2018 Google added possibility to specify how to treat the bounds in autocomplete predictions. Now you can use the  `getAutocompletePredictions()` method of `GeoDataClient` class with `boundsMode` parameter.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50134855/5140781 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. 
This though is set to my city. To anyone who would like to use this, just change the long and lat.
`sb.append("&types=establishment&strictbounds&location=9.30684,123.305447&radius=2000");`