# Google AutoComplete Api restrict to only city android

Tags: android, location, google-places-api

I am working on Google autocomplete api to show search results.

I wanted to restrict search results to `cities` eg **Mumbai**

I am successful in restricting to **country** but not cities

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?&components=country:in&key=**API_key**&input=carter

when I try **&components=administrative_area_level_3:mumbai** for city restriction , I get **INVALID_REQUEST**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search locations inside a particular city in Google Places Apis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940445/search-locations-inside-a-particular-city-in-google-places-apis)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we restrict google map autocomplete to only a particular city?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843110/how-can-we-restrict-google-map-autocomplete-to-only-a-particular-city)

Comment: This is [issue 4433](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4433) in the public issue tracker. Please star it to let Google know you are interested to have it implemented.